# swing flow layout break element

Tags: java, swing

I have panel which is using flow layout.

How can I make break in flow layout? Like `<br/>` in html. Some special break element or another trick to indicate that specified element and all subsequent have to go to the next line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a case like this, I'd put two containers with flowlayout one on top of each other inside a BoxLayout.  Nesting layouts is fairly inexpensive.

Comment: Heh, nesting is good, but not enough, it creates unnecessary gaps when container's height is big.

Comment: There is no reason for there to be gaps if you code them correctly.

Comment: Post a sample if you're at it.

Answer (score 12):

The [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) might be a solution for you. It automatically moves components to the next line when a line is full.

Answer (score 9):

You want to manually divide the components in multiple rows? So you know where you want the linebreak to be.

In that case I would use 3 panels:

- 1 panel containing the other 2 panels with a GridLayout with 1 column
- 2 panels inside the GridLayout, each with a FlowLayout

Example code:

```
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    {
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        {
            panel_1 = new JPanel();
            panel.add(panel_1);
            {
                lblPanelFlowlayout = new JLabel("Panel 2: FlowLayout");
                panel_1.add(lblPanelFlowlayout);
            }
        }
        {
            panel_2 = new JPanel();
            panel.add(panel_2);
            {
                lblPanel = new JLabel("Panel 3: FlowLayout");
                panel_2.add(lblPanel);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can add as many new Panels with a FlowLayout as you want. Each time you would do a BR you now set the next panel as active (possibly creationg it dynamically).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible in a flow layout, you might want to try another layout like [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) or [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make multiple placeholder panels with no insets, and then use some code to work out when a component needs to be moved to the next panel because it's below a minimum width threshold. It's ugly, but it should work. You'd need to do all the removal and addition by hand, and within the EDT.