# How to start a JLabel and a JTextField in a newline?

Tags: jpanel, jlabel, jtextfield

[image]

```
        panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        panel1.add(hp_label);
        panel1.add(health_field);

        panel1.add(money_label);
        panel1.add(money_field);
```

I would like to put the Money_label in the next line inline with the money_field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238309/swing-flow-layout-break-element

Comment: @schlagi123 I used the GridLayout now the problem is the text fields are too big and they fit the panel

Comment: I would use the GridBagLayout (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). There is an attribute for this (fill)